# gson won't deserialize a array

Tags: java, serialization, gson

Have the following json String:

```
[{"Custom":{"id":4,"name":"Lebensmittel","currency":"EUR","count":2}}]
```

This is a shortened version, normally i have a very long json string with a lot of "Custom" objects.
I receive the json String from a remote machine where i have no influence of.
I'm trying to use the following code to deserialze the json String:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Custom[] data = gson.fromJson(json, custom[].class);
```

The result is tht the size of the Array data is correct, but the content is null, no values are deserialized.

Here is the POJO class Custom

```
public class Custom implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1826747252056159012L;

private int id;

private String name;

private String currency;

private int count;

public Custom() {
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(final int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getCurrency() {
    return currency;
}

public void setCurrency(final String currency) {
    this.currency = currency;
}

public int getCount() {
    return count;
}

public void setCount(final int count) {
    this.count = count;
}

}
```

So, can anybody tell me what is wrog?

Thnaks in advance

Comment: Your json is more an array of some object that has a field of type `Custom` named "Custom"

Comment: i tried also to use a "wrapper" class which contains a list of custom objects. But that will also not be serialzed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error on your json :

```
[{"Custom":{"id":4,"name":"Lebensmittel","currency":"EUR","count":2}}]
```

must be

```
[{"id":4,"name":"Lebensmittel","currency":"EUR","count":2}]
```

Comment: The problem is, i receive the json from a remote machine which generate this json with a PHP generator. So i cannot change anything.

Comment: Just validate the json with jsonlint and it seems to be correct

Comment: In this case you must change your object Custom. And create an object with a property Custom and of Custom type

Comment: Jap, but in that case gson is throwing an Exception: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom `TypeAdapter` (or `JsonDeserializer` if you don't need serialization)

```
private static class CustomTypeAdapter  extends TypeAdapter<Custom>{
    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Custom value) throws IOException {
        if (value!= null)
         out.beginObject()
                 .name("Custom")
                 .jsonValue(gson.toJson(value))
                 .endObject();
    }

    @Override
    public Custom read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        Custom custom = null;
        in.beginObject();
        String name = in.nextName();
        if (name.equals("Custom")) {
            custom = gson.fromJson(in, Custom.class);
        }
        in.endObject();
        return custom;
    }
}
```

And register it like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
             .registerTypeAdapter(Custom.class, new CustomTypeAdapter())
             .create();
Custom[] data = gson.fromJson(json, Custom[].class);
```

---

Other option is to use custom wrapper like this:

```
public static class CustomWrapper{
    @SerializedName("Custom")
    public Custom custom;
}
```

Use case:

```
CustomWrapper[] data = gson.fromJson(json, CustomWrapper[].class);
```